# select data from array that matches condition in another array in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have 2 arrays i want to display the final array as what are the array element in $displayArray only be displayed  from the $firstArray

```
$firstArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Dis_id] => Dl-Dis1
        [Dis_Desc] => Discount
        [Dis_Per] => 7.500
        [Dis_val] => 26.25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Dis_id] => Dl-Dis2
        [Dis_Desc] => Discount
        [Dis_Per] => 2.500
        [Dis_val] => 8.13
    )

)

$displayArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Dis_id
        [1] => Dis_val
    )

)
```

i want the final output will be

```
$resultArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Dis_id] => Dl-Dis1
        [Dis_val] => 26.25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Dis_id] => Dl-Dis2
        [Dis_val] => 8.13
    )

)
```

Both the $firstArray and the $DisplayArray are dynamic but the $displayArray should be one.

i dont know how to do give me any suggestion

Comment: What if `$displayArray` has more items than one?

Comment: @Antti29 may be it occurs more than one it all about user select

Comment: `$displayArray` is a multidimensional array. You don't specify what you want to do when there are more than one item in it.

Comment: @Antti29 sry the $displayArray should be one and i get the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, if `$displayArray` will never have more than one array, the answer is pretty simple. Start by popping the inner array, to get to the actual keys you will need:

```
$displayArray = array_pop($displayArray);//get keys
$resultArray = array();//this is the output array
foreach ($firstArray as $data)
{
    $item = array();
    foreach ($displayArray as $key)
        $item[$key] = isset($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : null;//make sure the key exists!
    $resultArray[] = $item;
}
var_dump($resultArray);
```

This gives you what you need.
However, if `$displayArray` contains more than 1 sub-array, you'll need an additional loop

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach ($displayArray as $k => $keys)
{
    $resultArray[$k] = array();//array for this particular sub-array
    foreach ($firstArray as $data)
    {
        $item = array();
        foreach ($keys as $key)
            $item[$key] = isset($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : null;
        $resultArray[$k][] = $item;//add data-item
    }
}
var_dump($resultArray);
```

the latter version can handle a display array like:

```
$displayArray = array(
    array(
        'Dis_id',
        'Dis_val'
    ),
    array(
        'Dis_id',
        'Dis_desc'
    )
);
```

And it'll churn out a `$resultArray` that looks like this:

```
array(
    array(
        array(
            'Dis_id'  => 'foo',
            'Dis_val' => 123
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'Dis_id'   => 'foo',
            'Dis_desc' => 'foobar'
        )
    )
)
```

Job done

Comment: thanks for your excellent answer.. is there any problem in my question why they mark down my question

Comment: @rAm: Read through the help section on how to ask what is considered a _"good question"_. It should accurately describe the problem (you were a tad unclear about what should happen if `$displayArray` contained multiple elements). But you probably got a -1 because you didn't show any evidence you your trying to solve the problem by yourself first. You didn't show/tell us what research you did, you didn't show any code... possibly someone thought this was a _"fix my problem for me"_ kind of question

Comment: i dont know how to do thats why i didn't specify any sample code anyway thank you for your answer